# Transform data during replication between databases with different structure (schema)

Tags: mysql, database

I'm looking for an automated and reliable solution to share some data from a normalized mysql db to other denormalized mysql db. data structure are different in both databases.

Comment: How could we even begin to answer this extremely generic question. Push the data from database to the other. Write the SQL to denormalize it and INSERT it. What are you asking?

Comment: Use RethinkDB handle inserted data on app level and adapt data to for every MySQL structure

Comment: yes basically it's a select insert to query but I'm looking for something to be automated like replication .

Comment: @num8er I already have mysql master db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create same db structure on slave as in master,
2. Manage replication,
3. Write convertor script and convert updated data on slave server's master-copy to denormalized db.
4. **or** You've to work with mysql replication protocol and convert that data on-the-fly before inserting to denormalized db

BONUS:

When was googling: "**mysql replication data transform**"

I found software that has data transformation feature during replication:

https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.9/html/user-guide.html#_transforms

But don't think that I'll help You with dealing with it (:

Comment: I pretty liked your idea about create same structure as slave on master, I will think about it later but let's talk more about your number 4 ,all  articles I found was working on same structure so I asked here to find a practical way of handling that.

Comment: @Mini I hope You will deal with SymetricsDB, it seems promising (:

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out [Tungsten Replicator](https://github.com/vmware/tungsten-replicator). It allows you to transform data during replication, and it is even possible to replicate from one technology to another, although this is outside the scope of this question.